# Oracle query to find records took more than 24hrs to process

Tags: oracle, plsql, query-optimization

I am having a situation were I have to find out such records from the tables who takes more than 24 hrs two load in DW.

so for this I am having two tables

1. Table 1 :- Which contains the stats about each and every load
2. Table 2 :- Which contains the stats about when we received the each file to load

Now I want only those records which took more than 24 hrs to load.
The date on which I have received a file is in table 2 whereas when its load is finished in in table 1, so table2 may have more than 1 entries for each file.

I have developed a below query but it's taking more time

```
SELECT 
    rcd.file_date,
    rcd.recived_on as "Date received On",
    rcd.loaded_On "Date Processed On",
    to_char(rcd.recived_on,'DY') as "Day",
    round((rcd.loaded_On - rcd.recived_on)*24,2) as "time required"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        tbl1.file_date,
        (SELECT tbl2.recived_on 
         FROM ( SELECT recived_on 
                FROM table2 
                Where fileName = tbl1.feedName 
                order by recived_on) tbl2 
          WHERE rownum = 1) recived_on,
        tbl1.loaded_On,  
        to_char(tbl2.recived_on,'DY'), 
        round((tbl1.loaded_On - tbl2.recived_on)*24,2)
    FROM Table1 tbl1 ,
         Table1 tbl2
    WHERE
        tbl1.id=tbl2.id 
        AND tbl1.FileState = 'Success'
        AND trunc(loaded_On) between '25-Feb-2020' AND '03-Mar-2020' 
) rcd
WHERE (rcd.loaded_On - rcd.recived_on)*24 > 24;
```

Comment: What is your exact question here?

Comment: Firstly, you should use modern `JOIN` syntax when joining two tables.

Comment: @ErgiNushi - no matter how annoying you personally find the implicit join syntax, its use here is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot of your problem most likely stems from the use of the subquery in your column list of your inner query.  Maybe try using an analytic function instead.  Something like this:

```sql
SELECT rcd.file_date,
       rcd.recived_on AS "Date received On",
       rcd.loaded_On "Date Processed On",
       to_char(rcd.recived_on, 'DY') AS "Day",
       round((rcd.loaded_On - rcd.recived_on) * 24, 2) AS "time required"
FROM   (SELECT tbl1.file_date,
               MIN(tbl2.recived_on) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl2.filename) AS recived_on,
               tbl1.loaded_On
        FROM   Table1 tbl1
        INNER JOIN Table1 tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
        WHERE    tbl1.FileState = 'Success'
        AND      trunc(loaded_On) BETWEEN '25-Feb-2020' AND '03-Mar-2020') rcd
WHERE  (rcd.loaded_On - rcd.recived_on) * 24 > 24;
```

Also, you were selecting some columns in the inner query and not using them, so I removed them.